# Replace IPs in text accordingly

Tags: bash

So, I have a file with text something like this:

```
backend test_https_backend
        option  forwardfor
        mode tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server test-dr-worker-1 10.242.1.60:32000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-2 10.242.0.6:32000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-3 10.242.0.107:32000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        ........


backend test_webtrack_backend
        mode tcp
        option  forwardfor
        balance roundrobin
        server test-dr-worker-1 10.242.1.60:31000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-2 10.242.0.6:31000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-3 10.242.0.107:31000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        ........
```

Also I have an array, where specified a list of IPs:

```
10.242.1.19 10.242.3.20 10.242.0.72 ....
```

How can I put IPs from the list into the text? To have this:

```
backend test_https_backend
        option  forwardfor
        mode tcp
        balance roundrobin
        server test-dr-worker-1 10.242.1.19:32000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-2 10.242.3.20:32000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-3 10.242.0.72:32000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        ........


backend test_webtrack_backend
        mode tcp
        option  forwardfor
        balance roundrobin
        server test-dr-worker-1 10.242.1.19:31000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-2 10.242.3.20:31000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        server test-dr-worker-3 10.242.0.72:31000 check inter 10000 rise 2 fall 5 send-proxy
        .........
```

Need to replace IPs accordingly, so test-dr-workers should receive exact the same IP everywhere. Also need to check maybe IP already set, not replace that.
Is this possible to do via bash?

Comment: Thank you.
I did a lot of resaerch but in vain, my skills in bash are not so high, that's why I posted here, so even a hint to the right way will help.

Comment: @user37033 please, show us what you already tried! Post some piece of code!

Comment: add below my work.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is my work, please make some corrections if possible. my_array is array with IP list separated with spaces.

```
for i in "${my_array[0]}"
do
   sed -i 's/test-dr-worker-1.*:32000/test-dr-worker-1 $i:32000/g;s/test-dr-worker-1.*:31000/test-dr-worker-1 $i:31000/g' /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg."$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
   "
done

for i in "${my_array[1]}"
do
   sed -i 's/test-dr-worker-2.*:32000/test-dr-worker-2 $i:32000/g;s/test-dr-worker-2.*:31000/test-dr-worker-2 $i:31000/g' /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg."$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
   "
done

for i in "${my_array[2]}"
do
   sed -i 's/test-dr-worker-3.*:32000/test-dr-worker-3 $i:32000/g;s/test-dr-worker-3.*:31000/test-dr-worker-3 $i:31000/g' /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg."$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
   "
done
```

Is it possible ti join this For loops into one?

Answer (score 0):

A solution in awk with example text in the file iptxt:

```
awk -v ipadds=$( echo ${ipadds1[@]}) '
      BEGIN { 
              split(ipadds,ipadds1);
              cnt=1 
            } 
      /^backend/ { 
              cnt=1 
            } 
      /server/ { 
              match ($0,/([0-9]+\.{1,3}){3}[0-9]+/);
              $0=substr($0,0,RSTART-1)""ipadds1[cnt]""substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);
              cnt++ 
             }
               { 
              print $0 
             }' iptxt
```

On liner:

```
awk -v ipadds=$( echo ${ipadds1[@]}) 'BEGIN { split(ipadds,ipadds1);cnt=1 } /^backend/ { cnt=1 } /server/ { match ($0,/([0-9]+\.{1,3}){3}[0-9]+/);$0=substr($0,0,RSTART-1)""ipadds1[cnt]""substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);cnt++ }{ print $0 }' iptxt
```

Read the array, ipadds1 as a text variable ipadds in awk. Split the variable back into an array, ipadds1 using awks split function. Set a cnt variable to 1 to specify the beginning of the ipadds1 index. When we encounter a line beginning with "backend" we set cnt back to 1 as we need to start at the beginnings of the ipadds1 array again, otherwise, when "server" is encountered in the line, we use awk's match function to find the beginning and end of an ip address pattern match. We use this information to substitute the ip addresses in the ipadds1 array for the existing ip address, incrementing the cnt variable as we go to print the next IP address in the array